# numeric solution to matrix ODE with matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, numeric, numerical-methods, ode

I am now trying to solve a matrix ODE numerically, let's simplify my problem as follows:

```
%{ I don't know the best way to define a 4*4 matrix function%}
syms rho11(t) rho12(t) rho13(t) rho14(t);
syms rho21(t) rho22(t) rho23(t) rho24(t);
syms rho31(t) rho32(t) rho33(t) rho34(t);
syms rho41(t) rho42(t) rho43(t) rho44(t); 
%{ rho is a 4*4 matrix, each element is a function of time %}
rho=[rho11, rho12, rho13, rho14;rho21, rho22, rho23, rho24;rho31, rho32, rho33, rho34;rho41, rho42, rho43, rho44];

%{ define constant matrix %}
s2p=zeros(4,4);s1p=zeros(4,4);
s2p(1,2)=1;s2p(3,4)=1;s1p(1,3)=1;s1p(2,4)=1;
init=zeros(4,4);init(2,2)=1;

%{now we need to solve the following ODE %}
d(rho)/dt=-(rho *s1p - rho *s2p); 
%{initial condition:%} rho(0)=init
```

I know one way is to transform the matrix to a vector, but the actual equation I am doing is too complex to transform it myself. Can anybody tell me the code to make this transformation and solve the ODE? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the wikipedia page for the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), implemented in MATLAB as [`kron`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html)